# Why does MOTD and "landscape-sysinfo" show different disk usage to "df"?

Tags: 12.04, disk-usage, landscape, motd

I have several drives on my server mounted separately. They are getting close to full. When I `ssh` to my server, `motd` reports disk usage, for example:

```
=> /home is using 89.3% of 916.89GB
```

But if I run `df -h`, it reports:

```
/dev/sdd1       917G  826G   45G  95% /home
```

This happens for all my drives; `motd` consistently reports lower numbers. It looks likes `motd` runs `landscape-sysinfo` to report this information.

Why are they different and which is correct?

Comment: Is /home mounted on it's own partition? You are correct, landscape-sysinfo is used for the MOTD but it usually only reports disk usage for / unless there are separate partitions.

Comment: Yes, /home is a separate partition on its own disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I filed a bug to track this:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/landscape-client/+bug/1186154

I believe landscape-sysinfo should be changed to match df.

Answer (score 4):

Having a look at the `landscape-sysinfo` script which lives in */etc/update-motd.d/*  it is clear that the calculation of the disk space is being done with `cat /proc/partitions` rather than the `df` command.

Performing the same test on my machine but using */* as an example I get the same results, `cat /proc/partitions` shows less disk space being used while `df` shows a bit more disk usage. The method used to calculate the partition size is different hence the different results:

```
cat /proc/partitions 
major minor  #blocks  name
   8        5  606765056 sda5

df
Filesystem            1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5             597111968 53985732 512787984  10% /
```

Both are correct in their own calculations, I would rely on `df` to get a better indiciation of disk usage for your **/home** partition.

Comment: Thanks. I would still be interested to know exactly why they calculate the partition size differently. If /proc/partitions is the unformatted size, for example, then this would make MOTD misleadingly optimistic.